# Idiots guide to developing on wear-os

Tags: android, wear-os

I am looking for an idiot's guide to writing apps for wear-os. Any pointers to online resources would be great.

I have a phone app and what I want to do is mirror the app on a watch. The phone app has a UI component and a service component in its own VM. Can I use this service, running on the phone, to deliver data to the watch?

I am thinking something similar to the way maps works, I can use my phone to set a destination and navigate, then the watch starts showing me the map and directions so my phone can go in the pocket. I am not looking for just sending notifications.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by familiarizing yourself with [building simple Wear OS apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/). There are quick start projects for [basic sample apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AlwaysOn). You can also take a guided lesson for creating a Wear OS app through [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/always-on/index.html).

After you have familiarized yourself with how Wear OS works, you can start [integrating Maps API on Wear OS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/wear). You can create a map-based wearable app that runs directly on Wear OS by Google devices.